# calculating depth of a binary tree in Python

Tags: python, oop, methods, tree

I am new to programming and am trying to calculate the depth of a binary tree in Python . I believe that my error is because depth is a method of the Node class and not a regular function. I am trying to learn OOP and was hoping to use a method. This might be a newbie error...
Here is my code:

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, item, left=None, right=None):
        """(Node, object, Node, Node) -> NoneType
        Initialize this node to store item and have children left and right.
        """
        self.item = item
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def depth(self):
        if self.left == None and self.right == None:
            return 1

        return max(depth(self.left), depth(self.right)) + 1

i receive this error:

>>>b = Node(100)

>>>b.depth()

1 

>>>a = Node(1, Node(2), Node(3))

>>>a.depth()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Wing IDE 101 4.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 1, in <module>
    # Used internally for debug sandbox under external interpreter
  File "C:\Program Files\Wing IDE 101 4.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 15, in depth
builtins.NameError: global name 'depth' is not defined
```

Comment: +1 for the correct intuition of your problem.

Comment: For future reference, I believe that `new bee` is spelled `newbie`, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: The intuition is partially correct (calling `depth()` as a method solves the problem), but somewhat incomplete. The root cause that explains why you can't access the method from inside itself but you can with a regular function is a somewhat involved detail of how scope and class definition works in Python. When you call a regular module-level function, it's "global" scope will be the module it's defined in, which contains this function. However, the scope where methods are defined can be considered to be discarded after the type object created.

Comment: As a side note, you should always use `self.left is None`, not `self.left == None`, as [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) says. This protects you from badly-designed classes, and adds a performance boost, but the real reason is that "is None" stands out as the one Pythonic way to do it, and makes your code more readable to experienced Python coders.

Answer (score 13):

```
def depth(self):
    if self.left == None and self.right == None:
        return 1

    return max(depth(self.left), depth(self.right)) + 1
```

should be

```
def depth(self):
    return max(self.left.depth() if self.left else 0, self.right.depth() if self.right else 0) + 1
```

A more readable version:

```
def depth(self):
    left_depth = self.left.depth() if self.left else 0
    right_depth = self.right.depth() if self.right else 0
    return max(left_depth, right_depth) + 1
```

The issue is that there is no function `depth`.  It's a method of the `Node` object, so you would need to call it from the object itself (left and right).  I shortened the code to `self.left.depth() if self.left else 0` and `self.right.depth() if self.right else 0` in order to remove the checks you previously have (they're implicit now) since I believe it is entirely possible that the left is `None` while the right is a `Node` or vice versa, which would cause the original code to throw an `AttributeError` since `None` does not have a method `depth`.

**Edit**

In response to the question about the `<something> if <some condition> else <otherwise>` block:

The line gives `<something>` if `<some condition>` is true-y (treated as true), and `<otherwise>` if `<some condition>` is false-y (treated as false)

Comment: I believe you want to call `depth` since it is a function :)

Comment: Mashing it into one line is a bit unreadable, but this is the right answer.

Comment: Wouldn't `Node` need a `__bool__` or `__nonzero__` method for the `if self.left` tests to actually work?

Comment: @Marius: No, the default is to return the object itself, which is true in boolean contexts, and therefore `self.left` is a valid test for `self.left is not None`.

Comment: @Hamish I recoded it in a more readable form also.  Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: PS, @SnakesandCoffee: Nice explanation for why you can't just do `if self.left is None and self.right is None`. If the OP wanted to leave the structure as-is, he'd also have to write something like `elif self.left is None: return self.right.depth()+1` and `elif self.right is None: return self.left.depth()+1`. So, I think your version is more readable.

Comment: @Snakes and Coffee: Thank you very much for your help and detailed explanation! What does this line of code mean: if self.left else 0 - i have never seen an if and an else on the same line. Sorry for the newbie question...

Comment: @user2133075 if you found this answer to be the right answer, please click the green check mark next to the votes (it gives me 15 rep and you 2 I believe)

Comment: @user2133075 I added the explanation for the `a if b else c` lines

Answer (score 4):

For clarity I would suggest writing your `depth` method like this:

```
def depth(self):
    current_depth = 0

    if self.left:
        current_depth = max(current_depth, self.left.depth())

    if self.right:
        current_depth = max(current_depth, self.right.depth())

    return current_depth + 1
```

Comment: For clarity I would suggest not using the same name for the method and a local variable in it.

Comment: So all nodes have the same depth of 1? Why this?

Comment: @Hyperboreus: this is essentially what his code was doing, I didn't check the correctness. Simply gave a more readable pattern :)

Comment: @millimoose: fair enough, I'll change it :)

Comment: But why would you want to post deliberately wrong code? Both the question and the other answer do add 1 in the recursion.

Comment: The question was modified, my code reflects a working version of the original code. I did not check it for correctness

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming from this line:

```
return max(depth(self.left), depth(self.right)) + 1
```

You're using depth as a function and trying to apply it to the left and right nodes.  Because the left and right nodes are also nodes, they have the depth method.

You should be calling the depth method like this:

```
return max(self.left.depth(), self.right.depth()) + 1
```

The self parameter is implicitly passed to the depth method, but using it with the dot operator tells Python that this method belongs to a Node instance, and it is not some other function not bound to an object.

Answer (score 1):

You've got four cases to consider:

1. Both subtrees are empty.
2. The left subtree alone is empty.
3. The right subtree alone is empty.
4. Neither subtree is empty.

You've covered cases 1 and 4, but missed 2 and 3.
The fix:

```python
# Return height of tree rooted at this node.
def depth(self):
    if self.left == None and self.right == None:
        return 1
    elif self.left == None:
        return self.right.depth() + 1
    elif self.right == None:
        return self.left.depth() + 1
    else:
        return max(self.left.depth(), self.right.depth()) + 1
```